# for all/for each looping through a Delphi TCollection?

Tags: delphi, loops, tcollection

Does Delphi provide any nice way to iterate over TCollectionItems in a TCollection?

Something, perhaps, along the lines of...

```
for mycollectionitem in mycollection.Items do
  mycollectionitem.setWhatever();
```

That doesn't compile though

or is there really nothing I can do that's more elegant than this:

```
for num := 1 to mycollection.Count do
  mycollection.Items[num-1].setWhatever();
```

Comment: If you have to use the classic for-to loop I would write `for num := 0 to mycollection.Count - 1 do`, just saying.

Comment: Which version of delphi? What is the compiler error you face?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`For..in` loops are implemented as calls to `GetEnumerator` and the methods on the variable it returns.  The `Items` property is not an object, but an array property that maps silently to a getter/setter pair, so it can't return an enumerator, but `TCollection` itself does have a `GetEnumerator` method.

Thus:

```
for mycollectionitem in mycollection do
   mycollectionitem.setWhatever();
```

Be aware, though, that `TCollection` is not a generic class, so the type of the enumerator index variable will be `TCollectionItem`, and not whatever `ItemClass` you're working with.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `for..in` was introduced in Delphi 2007, so it won't work for older versions.

Comment: @Remy: Yes, but considering that the OP is using `for..in` syntax in the example, it's reasonable to assume he's working with a version that supports it.

Comment: The OP *wants* to use `for..in` syntax. That does not mean he actually *has* a Delphi version that supports `for..in` loops. Some other languages have similar `for..in` syntax, so he could just be speculating. He did not say anything that hints at the Delphi version he is using.